# network bridge not forwarding traffic from span port on router

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, ufw, lxc

I want to run several security network tools in LXC containers like ntopng, suricata, snort, etc.

I hooked one of my server's NIC's up to a port that is spanned to my firewall... so basically this NIC would see all of the traffic that's passing through the firewall. I added a bridge with brctl, and added the interface to the bridge. But no traffic was passed to the containers through the bridge...

`USE_LXC_BRIDGE="false"` is set in the lxc configuration.
`-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT` is in `before.rules` on the base installation. The LXC containers are using `veth` mode. If I set the network type to `phys` things work (for one container at a time), but this won't work if I want to run multiple tools!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've learned:

A Linux `bridge` is a misnomer... In the `brctl` world, a `bridge` behaves more like the `switch` of the networking world. Bridges are smart, in the sense they figure out what MAC addresses are attached to it and only forward ethernet frames to the bridge member that has a matching MAC address for efficiency. This is the behavior you'd expect out a physical networking switch.

The virtual software defined device I'm looking for is analogous to a networking `hub`... Where all frames are rebroadcast to all members of the hub, regardless of the MAC address the frame was destined for.

Clues:

- http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/brctl8.html
- https://rarforge.com/w/index.php/Port_mirror_(span)

So for my bridge `span0`:

```
brctl setageing span0 0
brctl setfd span0 0
```

or in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto span0
iface span0 inet manual
  bridge_ports em1
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_maxage 0
  bridge_ageing 0
```

whew. Hope this helps someone else!